# aHow to get child view from a Listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to change a child view of  ListView that I create When App starts. I wrote this code But doesn't work! How can I do that?

Because of more code don't let me to post.Because of more code don't let me to post.Because of more code don't let me to post.Because of more code don't let me to post.Because of more code don't let me to post.Because of more code don't let me to post.

```
ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

        ni=new Aye[text.returnString().length];  
            for(int i=0;i<text.returnString().length;i++){
                ni[i]=new Aye(Sura.this);
                ni[i].setarabic(getIntent().getExtras().getString("namesura").toString());
                ni[i].setarabic(text.returnString()[i]);
                ni[i].setnonarabic(ttext.returnString()[i]);
                tbstate=sp.getBoolean("a"+i, false);
                ni[i].setSelected(tbstate);

                results.add(ni[i]);
            }

        ArrayList image_details = results;
        lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, image_details));
        for(int i=0;i<ni.length;i++){       
        if(ni[i].isSelected()){
            lv1.getAdapter().getView(i, null, lv1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected);
            }
        }
```

Custom ListAdapter Class

```
package ir.aiga.apps.quran;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList listData;
    private Typeface tf;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "qt.ttf");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tv_arabic=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_arabic);
            holder.tv_nonarabic=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nonarabic);
            holder.tv_number=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
            holder.tv_arabic.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.tv_nonarabic.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.tv_number.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.tv_arabic.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.tv_number.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.tv_arabic.setTextSize(25);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Aye aye = (Aye)listData.get(position);
        aye.setNumber(position);
        holder.tv_arabic.setText(aye.getarabic());
        holder.tv_nonarabic.setText(aye.getnonarabic());
        holder.tv_number.setText(1+aye.getNumber()+"");


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_arabic;
        TextView tv_nonarabic;
        TextView tv_number;
    }

}
```

Comment: This Line dosn't do it's work.  lv1.getAdapter().getView(i, null, lv1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ListView` contains `Views` inside it so you just get the child view inside it that you want to change. You can use

```
lv1.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected);
```

If this is in your `onCreate()` then you will probably need to post a `Runnable` to the `ListView` for it to work because the `View` isn't completely drawn yet. So you would do something like

```
lv1.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        lv1.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected);
    }
});
```

I did something similar this way but changed it because it ended up being ugly and I found a better way. I'm not sure how it would work in the `loop` but you could try.

But since you seem to be using a Custom adapter, you could also change what you need by overriding the Adapters `getView()` method. Try adding it there with

```
Aye aye = (Aye)listData.get(position);

//add it here in getView()
if (aye.isSelected()) 
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected);

aye.setNumber(position);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? Does it crash or just does nothing? Have you checked to be sure it enters the `if` statement by using logs or breakpoints?

Comment: " Have you checked to be sure it enters the if statement by using logs or breakpoints?"

Comment: gave this error. 07-29 01:12:33.055: E/AndroidRuntime(16691): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: There's a lot more to the error message than that. The rest will tell you at one line something is null then you can inspect that line and find out what it is

Comment: When I click on error in logcat show me lv1.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected);

Comment: See my edit. If your first snippet is in `onCreate()` then it might now be drawn yet and will return null.

Comment: Thanks, Works correctly! My question is Why we can't do that with child view?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Where are you trying to do it with child view? Your approach or my initial approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should be interacting with child views in the `getView()` method of your `CustomListAdapter` class. Please post this class, and it can be shown how you can interact with your child views.